# Changing navbar color on scroll after 100vh

Tags: css, navbar, onscroll

I want to change the color of my navbar when I scroll more than 100vh (when I changed from a section to another). How can I do that? I tested this code, but it doesn't work.

```
const myNav = document.getElementById('header');
window.onscroll = function () { 
    "use strict";
    if (document.body.scrollTop > document.height ) {
        myNav.classList.add("scrolled");
    } 
    else {;
        myNav.classList.remove("scrolled");
    }
};
```

This is the CSS:

```
header {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    transition: 0.2s;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.scrolled {
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 1;
    
}
```

Comment: What is your CSS? As we will need to know that to answer this question, plus you tagged this with the CSS tag, so how could we answer this with just knowing the JavaScript that you tried. So please add the CSS.

Comment: Sure, I updated it. Sorry for the missundersanding

Comment: Did you try `window.innerHeight` instead of `document.height` in the if-condition?

Comment: @ManuelNelson That is okay.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work either. I have two sections: both of 100vh; I wanna give my navbar a background-color: white; when the scroll reaches the second section, but I don't know how

Comment: Could you show us the basic structure of the HTML too. Have you investigated IntersectionObserver. That could tell you when the second section comes into the viewport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the scroll position use `window.scrollY` and to get the veiwport height use `window.innerheight` so do:

```js
const myNav = document.getElementById('header')

window.onscroll = function() {
  if(window.scrollY > window.innerHeight){
    myNav.classList.add('scrolled')
  }else{
    myNav.classList.remove('scrolled')
  }
}
```

```css
body{
  min-height: 400vh;
}

nav{
  position:fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
}

nav.scrolled{
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<nav id="header"></nav>
```